# Reflection instead .NET-to-.NET scenario

Tags: c#, .net, dcom

I created Person.dll and register it(regsvcs.exe) in Command Promt for Visual Studio 2019. As a result of registration, I got Person.tlb. I tried to add Person.tlb in console project as reference COM component but I got warning MSB3290.

> warning MSB3290: Failed to create the wrapper assembly for type
> library "{8b1098cb-d453-4dc7-96ac-52df54d0a2ce}". Type library
> 'Person' was exported from a CLR assembly and cannot be re-imported as
> a CLR assembly.

How I can to add Person.tlb in console project using reflection?

Person.dll:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.EnterpriseServices;

namespace COM
{
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    public class Person : ServicedComponent, COM.IPerson
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public bool IsMale { get; set; }
        public void Persist(string FilePath)
        {
            StreamWriter oFile = new StreamWriter(FilePath);
            XmlSerializer oXmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Person));
            oXmlSerializer.Serialize(oFile, this);
            oFile.Flush();
            oFile.Close();
        }
        static public Person Retrieve(string FilePath)
        {
            StreamReader oFile = new StreamReader(FilePath);
            XmlSerializer oXmlSerilizer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Person));
            Person oPerson = oXmlSerilizer.Deserialize(oFile) as Person;
            return oPerson;

        }
    }
}
```

Console project:

```
using System;

namespace Test10
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            COM.Person per = new COM.Person();
            per.FirstName = "Maxim";
            per.LastName = "Donax";
            per.Persist(@" C:\myFile.xml ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This usually occurs when you attempt to wrap a type library created from an assembly compiled _against a different CLR version_ that the one you're using (eg. .NETFX 2.0 vs .NETFX 4.0 vs .NET Core).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used other way: created Person.dll in Visual Studio and registerd it(regsvcs.exe). After use reference Person.tlb in Visual Basic 6.0.